# How to protect custom url with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have application which is divided into 2 parts: GUI is in address localhost:8080/simple-gui and backend localhost:8080/simple-backend. In backend I have defined simple spring security (details are here: [Validate test user with spring security against database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026995/validate-test-user-with-spring-security-against-database)) Problem is this security protects all pages in simple-backend. How to protect also simple-gui and redirect all unauthorized users to login page: localhost:8080/simple-gui/login.html

Simple gui has nothing to do with java. It is just html so I cant create spring security there.

Comment: *"protect custom url"*  How does a 'custom' URL differ to a plain old  URL?

Comment: sorry I dont uderstand your question. I have application where is created spring security. But I also want to protect another application in the same server but with different url

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, both application seems to be separate wars when deployed in tomcat. So if you are thinking that adding configurations for simple-gui in simple-backend will also secure simple-gui, that I guess will not happen.

Either, you can have separate configurations for simple-gui in that project itself or What you need to study about is **SSO or OAUTH**, if you want to perform something like this.